# Add dynamic object to collection property of parent object

Tags: c#

I am using AutoMapper to map objects to each other.  One of my objects has several properties which are collections of other objects.  I have tried to come up with a generic way to map the various objects without knowing what they are until runtime.  Here is my sample code so far:

```
public class Person
{
    public List<Sibling> Siblings;
    public List<Pet> Pets;
    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles;
}

static void DoStuff(List<PersonInfo> people)
{
    Dictionary<Type, Type> dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
    {
        dictionary.Add(typeof(SiblingInfo), typeof(Sibling));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(PetInfo), typeof(Pet));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(VehicleInfo), typeof(Vehicle));
        //MANY MORE ENTRIES
        //.................
        //END
    }

    using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
    {
        foreach (PersonInfo personInfo in people)
        {
            Person newPerson = Mapper.Map<Person>(personInfo);

            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in personInfo.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsArray)
                {
                    Array array = (Array)propertyInfo.GetValue(personInfo);

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                    {
                        dynamic objectInfo = array.GetValue(i);

                        Type sourceType = objectInfo.GetType();

                        Type destinationType;

                        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(sourceType, out destinationType)) ;

                        dynamic newObject = Mapper.Map(objectInfo, sourceType, destinationType);

                        //HOW TO ADD THE NEW OBJECT TO ITS RESPECTIVE COLLECTION???
                        //newPerson.Siblings.Add(newObject);
                        //newPerson.Pets.Add(newObject);
                        //newPerson.Vehicles.Add(newObject);
                        //newPerson.HOW_TO_ADD_THIS.Add(newObject);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //DO MORE STUFF
        //........
        //END
    }
}
```

This does the mapping just fine regardless of type.  The problem I am struggling with is at the bottom of this code where I need to add the new object to appropriate collection property of the parent object.

How can I amend this code to add the new object to the appropriate collection?

Comment: Why not get respective collection property via reflection, then add object there?

Comment: @Evk That would be wonderful.  I have been struggling to do just that.  I apologize for not mentioning it before.  I would have shown some of the different things I have tried, but there has been so much throwaway code I'm not even sure if it would have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can just get collection property via reflection, then add new value there - like this:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {            
        var person = new Person();
        var prop = person.GetType().GetProperty("Siblings");
        var currentValue = (IList) prop.GetValue(person);
        currentValue.Add("new object");
        Console.WriteLine(person.Siblings);
    }
}

public class Person {
    public Person() {
        Siblings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Siblings { get; private set; } 
}
```

If collection property can be null - ensure you initialize it before adding value.